# Objective-C "cannot find protocol declaration"

Tags: objective-c

I created a simple protocol, by going to File, Add File...in Xcode.

Protocol: Cleaner.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol Cleaner <NSObject>
@required
-(int)addFirstNumber:(int)firstNum toSecondNumber:(int)secondNum;
@optional
-(void)returnString;
@end
```

Then in my class header I have:

Class header: Employee.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Employee : NSObject <NSCoding, Cleaner>
@property NSString *name;
@property NSDate *date;
@property (readonly)int age;
-(id)initWithAge:(int)age andName:(NSString*)name andDate:(NSDate*)aDate;
-(NSString*)description;
@end
```

I get the error message in the editor saying "cannot find protocol declaration" and pointing to the Cleaner protocol.

Am I missing something?
I didn't manually relocate files or anything, I created all files in Xcode by going to File, Add File, and selected the project folder as the location.

Comment: Did you import Cleaner.h into Employee.h?

Comment: `#import "Cleaner.h"` into your `Employee.h`

Comment: OKAY but you don't need to neg. Apple docs and their examples don't show the need to import a protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: This is basic C stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `#import "Cleaner.h"` at the top of `Employee.h`.

Comment: Even if the answer is correct, I would transform it in a comment. Just because the problem can be identified just by means of a Google search or SO one.